# Return/break out of infinite foreach in kotlin

Tags: foreach, kotlin, return, infinite

For class I have to make a program that calculates the birthday problem
Now I'm having trying to learn kotlin at the same time and I'm having trouble with a little snippet of code:

```
        val checkSet = mutableSetOf<Int>()
        generateSequence{ Random.nextInt(n)}.forEach {
            if(!checkSet.add(it)) {
                return@outForeach
            }
        }
        outForeach@
        sum += checkSet.size
```

As you can see I'm trying to do this with an infinite sequence. Kotlin doesn't accept this as outForeach is an unresolved reference. But this doesn't work either:

```
        val checkSet = mutableSetOf<Int>()
        generateSequence{ Random.nextInt(n)}.forEach {
            if(!checkSet.add(it)) {
                return@forEach
            }
        }
        sum += checkSet.size
```

This will just start the forEach loop again. Is there a way to implement something as a forEachUntil or so?

p.s. I'm aware that this looks a lot like this question: ['return' doesn't jump out of forEach in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056994/return-doesnt-jump-out-of-foreach-in-kotlin) It's just that I don't really get the answers and I don't know if its applicable here. Also a way to implement forEachUntil seems for me to be far more elegant

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives you may want to consider instead of [`first`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first.html#first):

- using a simple [`while`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#while-loops) without body:

  ```
  while (checkSet.add(Random.nextInt(n))); // <- that semicolon is required! otherwise you execute what is coming next within the while
  ```
- using [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html#run) with a label:

  ```
  run outForeach@{
    generateSequence{ Random.nextInt(n)}.forEach {
      if(!checkSet.add(it)) {
        return@outForeach
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- maybe also [`takeWhile`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take-while.html#takewhile) might be helpful. In this specific case however it is surely not (as it would check against the `checkSet` and leave us with a sequence that isn't consumed... but if the condition would be different, it may make sense to consider something like [`take`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take.html), [`takeWhile`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take-while.html#takewhile), [`takeLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take-last.html), etc.):

  ```
  generateSequence { Random.nextInt(n) }
      .takeWhile(checkSet::add) // as said: for this specific condition it doesn't make sense... 
      .forEach { /* do nothing except consume the sequence */ } // the same values you added to the set would be available in this step of course
  ```

Comment: the while loop is definitely a more elegant solution as it produces no unused sequence or reference.

Comment: that's true and while it works quite well for this specific example it may not in other cases where a real ~return is wanted.... (although I don't know any such cases that really require a goto-label-construct, that aren't also solveable using other means)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution myself:

```
        val checkSet = mutableSetOf<Int>()
        generateSequence{ Random.nextInt(n)}.first { !checkSet.add(it) }
        sum += checkSet.size
```

Basically use the function first() and keep returning false until you want to get out of the loop. And just drop the return of the function first()

Comment: It says I can do that in two days